# How to use <button type=button>

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I’m usually Using input type submit eg: `<input type=“submit” name=“assign” value=“Assign”/>`
and using this is no problem for me but now I want to use button eg:`<button type=“button” class=“button” id=“deleteb”><div>Assign Student</div></button>`
but don’t know how to used it or call it to my controller.

this is my controller function

```
if($assign_student)//<input type="submit" name="assign" value="Assign"/>
{
    if($maxMember->max_members > $countMember)
    {
        if($countMember+1 == 1)
        {
            $is_leader  = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $is_leader = $this->input->post('is_leader');
        }
        $student = array(
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('student'),
            'group_no' => $this->input->post('group'),
            'is_leader' => $is_leader
            );

        $this->admin_db->save_group($student['group_no'],$student);   
    }
    else
    {
        $data['max_error'] = "<p class='error'>Sorry, This group reached the maximum number of members!</p>";
    }  
}
```

Comment: It's `button type="submit"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to submit the form you must have `type="submit"`

If you want the button to send a value, it's better to use a hidden input to send along additional information. Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="assign" value="Assign" />
```

You *can* set a name and value to the `<button>`, but guess what?: In IE6, the actual ***html content*** of the button will be sent as the post data instead. It's one of my favorite bugs.

It's not very clear why you posted your controller code, but if you are checking for a "trigger" value before processing, like `$this->input->post('assign')`, you can check for the presence of any other of the form values instead, or the presence of *any* `$_POST` values, or as I mentioned: a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

If you press a submit-button, you are posting a form to some
script, in this case PHP.

if you submit the form, your browser sends the information
contained in the form to the receiving script.

eg, if you make a page with a form that contains:

You can check like this...

```
if (isset($_POST["deleteb"]))
{
//Do stuffs
}
```